# Switch device camera in Unity 3d

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, camera, crop, unityscript

I am using WebCamTexture class to open camera from device. I want to switch camera from front to back and vice versa in between the game play. Can anybody help?

```
    WebCamDevice[] devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    WebCamTexture   webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture(devices[1].name);
    renderer.material.mainTexture = webCamTexture;
    webCamTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Trilinear;
    webCamTexture.Play();
```

This opens my front camera. But I can't switch the camera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. You just need to set the name of the device. By default back camera is "Camera 0" and "Camera 1" front camera. First Stop your camera , change the set device.

```
if (devices.Length > 1) {
         webCamTexture.Stop();
        if (frontCamera == true)
        {
            webCamTexture.deviceName = devices[0].name;
            frontCamera = false;
        }
        else
        {
            webCamTexture.deviceName = devices[1].name;
            frontCamera = true;
        }
         webCamTexture.Play ();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code for switching the front and back camera of the iPhone Device using C# script

```
WebCamDevice[] devices;

public WebCamTexture mCamera = null;
public GameObject plane; // this is the object where i am going to show the camera

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    devices = WebCamTexture.devices;

    plane = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");

    mCamera = new WebCamTexture (Screen.width,Screen.height);
    mCamera.deviceName = devices[0].name;  // Front camera is at Index 1 and Back Camera is at Index 0
    plane.renderer.material.mainTexture = mCamera;
    mCamera.Play ();

}
```

the above code will show the back Camera when the Scene is loaded ,for accessing the front camera on the click of front button defined below

```
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (100, 1000, 120, 40), "Front"))
    {
        if(devices.Length>1)
         {
            mCamera.Stop();
            mCamera.deviceName = (mCamera.deviceName == devices[0].name) ? devices[1].name : devices[0].name;
            mCamera.Play();
        }

    }
```

This is button, by clicking it will redirect to front camera and again clicking it will redirect to back camera alternatively

Answer (score 0):

```
if (devices.Length > 1) {
     webCamTexture.Stop();
    if (frontCamera == true)
    {
        webCamTexture.deviceName = devices[0].name;
        frontCamera = WebCamTexture.devices[0].isFrontFacing;
    }
    else
    {
        webCamTexture.deviceName = devices[1].name;
        frontCamera = WebCamTexture.devices[1].isFrontFacing;
    }
     webCamTexture.Play ();
}
```

We've used Camera Capture Kit for a social image sharing game/app to do a similar functionality to what you are describing, The other solution presented here is not 100% solid, since there might potentially be devices with different order of front and back-facing devices.